# Can I manually set the platform name in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am developing a Python script which should be running under both Windows and Linux.

In my script I use platform.system() to determine the OS.

Because I use Pycharm in Windows, platform.system() always retrun "Windows". I couldn't directly test the Linux branch locally.

Is there a simple way to setup Pycharm, so I can choose what will be returned when platform.system() is called?

Comment: Could you not for the sake of testing, pass the platform as an argument? i.e `myscript.py -linux`

Comment: Can do it locally, maybe not in production.

Comment: But wouldn't the platform be known in production? Why would you still want to fake a different platform in production? BTW, on linux `platform.system()` returns, unsurprisingly, `'Linux'`.